# towers of hanoi - python - recursion

Tags: python, recursion

i know there are a lot of questions to this topic but i didnt find a answer to my question.

i found a code to solve the tower of hanoi problem. This is the code:

```
def move(x, y):
    print(f"move disc from {x} to {y}")

def solve_hanoi(n, frompoint, helper, destination):
    if n == 0:
            pass
    else:
        solve_hanoi(n-1, frompoint, destination, helper)
        move(frompoint, destination)
        solve_hanoi(n-1, helper, frompoint, destination)

solve_hanoi(3, "A", "B", "C")
```

The first few steps I understand till the ouput "Move disc from A to C". But I don't understand how the next output is "move from A to B" (it's [step 26 in Live Programming Mode](http://pythontutor.com/live.html#mode=edit)).

Because after the function move, the function solve_hanoi(n-1, helper, frompoint, destination) is on turn. n-1 is now 0, so the function will be passed. But why is also the tuple with n=1 passed??

Hope you understand my problem and can help me.

Kind regards

Comment: Note the stack frame. The output "from B to A" comes from an earlier function call moving on; "from A to C" does not make any more calls. Looking into in-order tree traversal might help you understand.

Comment: Conceptualize a call to `solv_hanoi(n,...)` as meaning "move a pile of size n from the source to the destination making use of the spare spindle."  This is accomplished by moving the pile of size n-1 to the spare, exposing the bottom disk, which you can move to the destination, and then move the pile of size n-1 from the spare to the destination.  Recursive calls relocate piles, while calls to `move` move an individual disc.  As written, the base case is to move a pile of size 0, which does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the second call just after the call to `move` will also get `n=0` and will just return without doing anything.  But then the recursion backtracks to the caller, which was also pending a return from the *first* recursive call in its `else` block. But in that context `n` is 2.

It may help to picture the recursion stack, i.e. the list of function executions that are pending for a recursive call to return to them:

```
solve_hanoi(n=3, frompoint="A", helper="B", destination="C")
    solve_hanoi(n=2, frompoint="A", helper="C", destination="B")
        solve_hanoi(n=1, frompoint="A", helper="B", destination="C")
            solve_hanoi(n=0, frompoint="A", helper="C", destination="B")
                pass
                return
            move(x="A", y="C") # frompoint, destination
                print("move disc from A to C")
                return
            solve_hanoi(n=0, frompoint="B", helper="A", destination="C")
                pass
                return
            return
        move(x="A", y="B")  # note how this move is not at the same depth as the previous one
            print("move disc from A to B")
            return
        solve_hanoi(n=1, frompoint="C", helper="A", destination="B")
            # ... etc
```

Comment: thank you very much! i drawed an in-order tree by myself and with your help I was able to reconstruct the code. But it's very tricky and it's just n=3. How can I do it the other way around: if I have the order tree, how can I do the recursion code?

Comment: There is no straightforward way to translate a generic tree problem into recursion code. You need to identify what the "base case" is (what characterises a leaf), and has to happen *before* the recursion step, and what *after*. If the tree is not necessary binary, then you would probably have a loop over the "children", and make the recursive call for each child. The variations are countless.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your question. I tried running your code in the live programming site and the function with n=1 is NOT being passed.

When the frame with n=1 is taken "off", the function call is executed and it calls solve_hanoi(0, frompoint, destination, helper) (which is passed obviously), then move() is executed and finally solve_hanoi(0, helper, frompoint, destination) is called which is also passed.

I don't understand what the problem is as everything is executing correctly